# jQuery gallery that scrolls horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css

I haven't been able to find a tutorial/plug in that lets you scroll through an image gallery horizontally.

This is what I'm looking for: http://bthomstevenson.com/NO-TIME-FOR-PRAYERS

Any links? Thanks.

Comment: Per the flagging menu: _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it."_...

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of tutorials teaching how to make a site scroll horizontally. I prefer [this one.](http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2012/horizontal-scrolling-with-jquery/) 
This code snippet is what's making the page scroll horizontally when scrolling with the mouse (remember you also have to include a certain js-file mentioned in the tutorial to make it all working).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
       this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity...if you are assigning the event to the wildcard operator selector, why would you need to include html and body? They should be included no? On a different note, the wildcard seems like it would be outrageously inefficient.

Comment: @War10ck You're totally right, of course there's no need for `html, body` if you already have `*` as selector. Edited my answer.

Comment: Cool. I was just checking. Wasn't sure if I was missing something. Nifty little solution. I'll have to remember this. +1 :)